# RELEASE Failed. 2561 for mload in teradata

Tags: teradata

I am trying to release mload from DBC.ABC as below.

Release mload DBC.ABC ;
or 
release mload DBC.ABC  in apply.

But getting below error.

RELEASE Failed. 2561:  MLoad related table DBC.ABC has bad usage field in table header

Comment: Do you have the log file from MultiLoad that led to this error? Can you post it?

Answer (score 0):

If the MultiLoad was in APPLY phase you really have two options:

1. Drop all the MultiLoad related tables (Work Table, UV table, Error Table, etc.). Drop the table that was being loaded. Restore the table from your last backup.
2. Get the MultiLoad to complete because you don't have a reliable backup of the table and dropping it is not a valid option.

You may also wish to consult with the Teradata Global Support regarding this situation if the table is a critical table in your production environment.

Comment: I dont have log for this mload. I am part of support group do i was cleaning temporary tables and mload locks created by some other users.

Comment: Without the log files clearing the work tables and MultiLoad locks associated with MultiLoad is a like navigating a minefield without a map.